# How to pass functions dynamically to angular forkJoin()?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, fork-join

I'm passing to the **sources** array two functions dynamically, but I'm having a problem when only one function is being passed.

How to mock empty observable, so if the second function is passed to not have it mapped with a, but with b.

```
 let sources = [];
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(email_address)) {
      sources.push(this.commonService.lookUpEmailAddress(emailParameters));
    }
    if (!isNullOrUndefined(telephone_number)) {
      sources.push(this.commonService.lookUpTelephoneNumber(telephoneParameters));
    }
   
    forkJoin(...sources)
      .subscribe(
      ([a, b]) => { // do stuff here }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can always has two observables, some like

```
sources=[
!isNullOrUndefined(email_address)?
          this.commonService.lookUpEmailAddress(emailParameters):
          of(null),
!isNullOrUndefined(telephone_number)?
          this.commonService.lookUpTelephoneNumber(telephoneParameters):
          of(null)
]
```

Then in subscribe check if a==null or b==null

Answer (score 0):

You could pass a variable that holds the array, instead of an explicit array `[a, b]`. Try the following

```js
forkJoin(...sources).subscribe(
  (response) => { 
    // response[0] - a - result from 1st observable in sources
    // response[1] - b - result from 2nd observable in sources (don't access response[1] if there is no 2nd observable)
  }
);
```

Now you could access the elements of the result that you know exist. For eg. `response[1]` is undefined if there is no 2nd element in the `sources` array.

Comment: I tried this, but it didn't work, because the second function is going to the [0] of the array, so it's not mapped correctly.